# Running a terminal command permanently

Tags: linux, process

I am currently hosting my database for free on Openshift and have my program running on a linux box on my local server. I need to pass the data from the program to my openshift database. I want to run the linux box headless.

To do this I run the command:

```
rhc port-forward -a webapp
```

My question is how can I run this command permanently without it timing out (some checking to see if process is running?) and without a terminal running (background process)?

Comment: This question makes more sense on unix&linux, and the details depend on what linux distro. In general, you'll want the equivalent of an rc.N script, but you might be on a systemd system.

Answer (score 2):

You could add that command in the startup settings of your Linux computer. So a `systemd`  configuation, or an `init` one (details could depend upon your particular distribution and system). See [systemd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/init.1.html) and/or [sysvinit](http://www.linuxvoodoo.com/resources/howtos/sysvinit)

You could also use [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html). It can be used for periodic tasks, but also for started once tasks, thru  some `@reboot` entry.

At last, you might use *batch* facilities, look into [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) (& `batch`)

Perhaps you may just want [nohup(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) (or [screen(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html)...)